# Getting 'It is illegal to run command renameCollection in a multi-document transaction'

Tags: java, mongodb

Getting this exception when I use below code from Java.

```
db.getCollection(collectionName).renameCollection(session, new MongoNamespace(db.getName(), newCollectionName));
```

I went through Mongo DB documentation and mentioned some of the operations are restricted in multi document transactions.

1. If its restricted why does this method gets session as input?
2. How to execute this in the middle of the transaction ?

Got the same error while `listCollectionNames` and `createCollection` as well.

Comment: 1. Session were added in v3.6 for casual consistency. They can be used without transactions added in v4.0  2. there is no way.